# Relationship between CDF and Random Variable

Tags: probability

Why is the distribution of a random variable uniquely determined by it CDF?

Comment: Reasonable question.  It is quite reasonavle that OP not have the requisite tools.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose two real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same cdf. The collection of sets $(-\infty,a]$ forms a $\pi$-system $\mathcal P$, and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$. The collection $\mathcal{D}$ of Borel-measurable sets $A$ for which $P(X \in A)=P(Y \in A)$ is a $\lambda$-system containing $\mathcal{P}$. By the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, $\mathcal{D}\supseteq \sigma(\mathcal P) = \mathcal B$, so $\mathcal D=\mathcal B$. That is, $P(X \in A)=P(Y \in A)$ for all Borel-measurable sets $A$, i.e., $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If two Borel probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb R$ agree on all the sets $(-\infty, a]$,

1. they also agree on $(-\infty, a)$ (since $\mu((-\infty, a)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu((-\infty, a - 1/n])$)
2. therefore on all open intervals $(a,b) = (-\infty, b) \backslash (-\infty,a]$
3. therefore (since an open set is a disjoint union of intervals) on all open sets
4. and by outer regularity on all Borel sets.